# Factoring and Exponent rules using "n" notation tripping me up

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Hello StackExchange world,

While doing a proof, I encountered:
$$ 
= S(n-1)+3^n-3^{n-1}
$$

I am focused on the latter part, with the powers of n, apparently it reduces after factoring to:

$$
2*3^{n-1}
$$

and I have no idea why. I tried thinking of n as a concrete number, and then n-1 the one before that, and I still can't wrap my mind around it. I am hoping someone can enlighten me here. Thank you all for the time and effort.

Comment: $3^n=3*3^{n-1}$ and you've subtracted another $3^{n-1}$ so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3^n-3^{n-1}=3.3^{n-1}-3^{n-1}=3^{n-1}(3-1)=2.3^{n-1}.$ I think you thought it as $3^{n}-3(n-1)$,which is not right.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I need to learn these little formatting tricks, would of made the algebra so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple. It suffices to factor out $3^{n-1}$ and note that $3^{n-1} \times 3 = 3^{n}$.

$$ 3^{n} - 3^{n-1} = 3^{n-1}(3 - 1) = 2 \times 3^{n-1} $$

Comment: thank you. I believe avatar said the same thing as well. I see it now. Any additional tips for manipulating these you could possibly reference me to?

Comment: This [pdf](http://www.freeteachingresources.ca/Exponent%20laws%20and%20factoring%20tips.pdf) seems to cover most of the basic laws for exponentiation. There's no magic here, whenever you see similar numbers/letters, try factoring them out. But the best piece of advice anyone could give is for you to get a good night's sleep. It does miracles.